# Should the blood of the Olah be burned or poured out?

Tags: tanach, deuteronomy, parashat-vayikra

Shalom. I’ve just noticed that Devarim 12:27 says that the blood of the Olah should be burnt on the altar. However Vayikra 1:5 says that the blood should be dashed against all sides of the altar. Has anyone explained this apparent discrepancy? Many thanks!

Comment: Besides for @sabbahillel's (correct) answer, the Talmud explains that the comparison - it doesn't actually say that the blood should be burned, just that it should go on the altar - is meant to indicate that the limbs of the Olah should reach the altar by being thrown, just as the blood is (i.e., the Kohanim stand on the ramp and throw the pieces into the fire).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a discrepancy. The statement in [Rei 12:27](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9976/showrashi/true#v27)

> And you shall make your burnt offerings the flesh and the blood upon
>   the altar of the Lord, your God, and the blood of your sacrifices
>   shall be poured upon the altar of the Lord, your God, and you shall
>   eat the flesh.

is a general case. Rav Isaac Levy, Rabbi Shimson Refael Hirsch's grandson (who translated the German to English) explains the *pouring of blood* to be

> pouring what is left of the blood down the base of the altar after the
>   "main service of the blood" - the prescribed sprinklings - has been
>   performed

That is, the pesukim in Vayikra such as [Vayikra 1:5](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9902/showrashi/true#v5)

> And he shall slaughter the young bull before the Lord. And Aaron's
>   descendants, the kohanim, shall bring the blood, and dash the blood
>   upon the altar, around [the altar] which is at the entrance of the
>   Tent of Meeting.

give the details of each korbon and the specific actions that are to be done before the the final spilling of the blood at the base of the altar.